# Como eliminar Servicios de Oracle Databse XE

Tags: oracle

Quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con este problema ya que quise reinstalar  el Oracle Database XE y  al momento de hacerlo me salia que debia desintalar el anterior lo hice pero  salia eso [!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busque en intenet y descubri que todavia tenia servicios del anterior y salia que una de las formas para eliminarlos era desde el editor de regristro pero despues de hacerlo sigue apareciendo eso y en Servicios se ven asi  y cuando intento ver que pase me sale que el archivo no esta obviemente por que lo elimine pero no entiendo por que sigue asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y intente eliminarlos desde cmd con `sc delete`  y `sc stop`  pero me sale estos errores respectivamente `[SC] OpenService ERROR 5:` y  `[SC] ControlService ERROR 1062:`
de por si acaso en el log me aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de esa imagen hay otra carpeta que dice también log dentro con esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esa Carpeta XE se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que puse muchas imágenes y todo pero estoy buscando el por que de este error desde el viernes no se si pueden ayudarme